# Prove that $a + (b+(c+d)) = (a+b) + (c+d)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

I'm working through Spivak's Calculus and the first section is covering associativity of addition.  I am only given $P1: a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$. I obviously know this intuitively but I cannot make the bridge in logic. It's a trivial proof and the fact I cannot prove something like this means I have a weakness that I'd like to rectify immediately before I dive further into the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal to struggle at "intuitive" proofs at the beginning, keep working and you'll get oast it.

Regarding your question, a binary operation $•$ is associative when for any $a,b,c$, $a•(b•c)=(a•b)•c$. Namely the placement of the parentheses doesn't affect the expression.

You can use it as follows define $e=(c+d)$.
Then
$$
a+(b+(c+d)) = a+(b+e) = (a+b)+e=(a+b)+(c+d)
$$

Comment: That's far more concise of a proof than my previous comment. Thank you both! However I do not know who to award the answer to. I do not wish to discount Nick's approach at giving me a hint and different perspective, but I also benefited from your explanation as well. Is there an etiquette of some sort on who gets the green checkmark?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Glad I could help however.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help you to rewrite P1 with different letters:
$$
x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z.
$$
Now the result you want is just a matter of choosing how to define $x$, $y$, and $z$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: I thought of this. So I'll let $x = (a + b)$, $y = c$ and $z = d$. Which will give me $(a+b) + (c+d) = ((a+b) + c) + d$. Which.. ahahah okay yeah that works because I previously proved that $((a+b) + c) + d = (a+(b+c)) +d = a+(b+(c+d))$. I was too stuck on trying to rearrange $a+(b+(c+d))$ to make $(a+b)+(c+d)$. Your approach is what I was missing.

Comment: @user357335 You would find a much more straight shot taking $x=a$, $y=b$, and $z=(c+d)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also approach it as follows: prove associativity within the context of the natural numbers $\textbf{N}$ and then extend such property to $\textbf{Z}$, $\textbf{Q}$ and $\textbf{R}$. Let us prove such claim in the context of $\textbf{N}$ using the Induction axiom on $c\in\textbf{N}$. Clearly, when $c = 0$, the proposed relation holds:
\begin{align*}
a + (b + c) = a + (b + 0) = a + b = (a + b) + 0
\end{align*}
and we are done. Now suppose such relation holds for some $c\in\textbf{N}$ and we shall prove it holds for $s(c)$, where $s:\textbf{N}\to\textbf{N}_{>0}$ is the successor function. Our induction hypothesis is given by:
\begin{align*}
a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c
\end{align*}

Then one has that:
\begin{align*}
a + (b + s(c)) & = a + s(b + c)\\\\
& = s(a + (b + c))\\\\
& = s((a + b) + c)\\\\
& = (a + b) + s(c)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

**EDIT**

Apparently, I have misread the title of the question. The corresponding solution is given as follows:

\begin{align*}
a + (b + (c + d)) & = a + ((b + c) + d)\\\\
& = (a + (b + c)) + d\\\\
& = ((a + b) + c) + d\\\\
& = (a + b) + (c + d)
\end{align*}

Hopefully it contributes!